# Unresolved external symbol referenced in function error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've looked at other people's solutions to this problem and none of them, unfortunately, have solved my issue. I was having this error in my dev project, so I started from scratch, followed [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1085171/How-To-Do-Unit-Testing-with-Cplusplus-in-Visual-St) to the letter, including the file names and locations, and I am still getting

> 1>unittest1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   static int __cdecl HelloWorld::getTwo(void)"
>   (?getTwo@HelloWorld@@SAHXZ) referenced in function "public: void
>   __thiscall UnitTest1::UnitTest1::TestMethodGetTwo(void)" (?TestMethodGetTwo@UnitTest1@1@QAEXXZ)
>
> 1>unittest1.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall
>   HelloWorld::getN(void)const " (?getN@HelloWorld@@QBEHXZ) referenced in
>   function "public: void __thiscall
>   UnitTest1::UnitTest1::TestMethodGetN(void)"
>   (?TestMethodGetN@UnitTest1@1@QAEXXZ)

The code is in the tutorial I linked but I will copy it below. I don't understand what I could be doing wrong at this point - my test project depends on my build project, my definitions for these functions are in the class.

HelloWorld.h

```
#pragma once
class HelloWorld
{
    int n = 10;
public:
    static int getTwo();
    int getN() const;
};
```

HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HelloWorld.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

int HelloWorld::getTwo()
{
    return 2;
}

int HelloWorld::getN() const
{
    return n;
}
```

unittest1.cpp (in test project)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../HelloWorld/HelloWorld.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTest1
{
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethodGetTwo)
        {
            Assert::AreEqual(2, HelloWorld::getTwo());
        }

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethodGetN)
        {
            HelloWorld hw = HelloWorld();
            Assert::AreNotEqual(0, hw.getN());
        }
    };
}
```

For some reason the linker can't find my definitions, and I'm out of ideas about why that might be.

Comment: Where is `getTwo` defined?  I didn't see it in your post.

Comment: In HelloWorld.cpp: int HelloWorld::getTwo(){    return 2;}

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you missed the project dependencies part of the tutorial.  The linker doesn't want the definition, it wants the object file so it can link in the compiled version of the functions.

Comment: Oh man, you're right, I did misread it. I didn't add the individual cpp and h files because I (incorrectly) assumed that adding them as a build dependency would do that. Thanks, that fixed it!